# How to handle heights of fluid divs?

Tags: html, css, height, zero

A Case: a **div** is **inside** **div**.

When child div that contains some text and is made float to left using CSS3 float property, the parent div's **height** becomes **zero**.

**what** is the cause of this and any solution?

*Note: the div's sizes are in percentage(**%**).*

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS, otherwise it is hard for people to help you.

Comment: i'll take note of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating an element takes it out of the normal flow of elements with one of yhe side effects being that it will no longer influence the dinensions of its parent element.

The easiest way to clear a `float` is to set the parent's `overflow` property to `hidden`.

However, this may be undesirable as you could have elements nested in the parent that you *need* to overflow it. In that case, use the `:after` pseudo element to clear the floated element.

```
.parent:after{
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:0;
}
```

A third solution is to simply give a sibling following the floated element the `clear` property but that one obviously depends on your layout and markup.

Incidentally, `float` is not a CSS3 property, it's been around for a while.